# Conditional probability with three variables

Tags: probability

A survey is conducted on $100$ people about their education background and work experience. There are $52$ males and $48$ females. $21$ males and $12$ females have no Bachelor degree and no work experience. There are 50 people with Bachelor degrees, and 60 people with work experience. What is the number of people with both Bachelor degrees and work experience out of these 100 people?

I was thinking of using Bayes theory to calculate:
Pr(Bachelors $\cap$ Work) = Pr(Bachelors) * Pr(Work|Bachelors)
P(bachelors) = 0.5

But then I can't figure out how to calculate P(Work|Bachelors).

How should I approach this problem?

Comment: The answer should be 43

Comment: OP: Why add this comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How should I approach this problem?

Forget probability, conditional or otherwise, and count:

- 50 people have a Bachelor degree
- 60 people have work experience
- 100-21-12=67 people have a Bachelor degree or work experience

Hence 50+60-67=43 people have a Bachelor degree and work experience.

Comment: Did you use Venn diagrams to figure this out?

Comment: To "figure this out", I used the fact that the number of people who can speak Chinese and Russian is the number of people who can speak Chinese plus the number of people who can speak Russian minus the number of people who can speak Chinese or Russian. Venn diagrams can help explain this fact.